# Sound popup showing every minute in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, notification

I have the sound popup thingy displayed about every minute, even without changing any volume settings, or clicking/pressing anything. It's happening in xubuntu 13.10 and looks like this

[image: looks like this]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anything, I got it fixed by killing `xfce-volumed` with `killall xfce-volumed`. Also removing it from autostart is needed:

> going to Xfce 4 Settings Manger -> Session and Startup -> Application
>   Autostart and then unchecking XFCE Volume Daemon and Volume Control

Now I don't get that annoying popup.

Btw here's another user having this problem (where I got the idea from): http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/How-to-disable-notification-popups-td43164.html

Comment: 1.5 years later, I found my own post and this solution worked for me again, only on xubuntu 14.04 this time. Thanks for posting this reply, past me!

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard media keys, they are the usual suspects. Also verify what key combination you have to change the volumes, if you have set a more common key. If it's regular check the cron jobs using `cron -e` and any running script using `ps ax | grep $USER`

Comment: I'm not even pressing anything - it still appears. Keyboard has no meia keys, crontabs for my user and root are empty. Not sure what to look for among running scripts? Also, can I disable that notification completely?